# Redirect authenticated users according to their role

Tags: laravel

I need to redirect users based on ther role in application. In MySQL, I've added "isAdmin" column in Users table to check whether user is admin or not. Only solution I've come up with is to render html on the same blade according to user's type. 
For example.

```
@if(Auth::user()->isAdmin == 1)
<p>Hello, Admin</p>
//other html for admin

@else
//other html for users
```

Is there a better way to do this in terms of more beautiful and efficient code because this looks messy?
I'm using this package (https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel) which uses Laravel's default authentication system.

I want to redirect users during their login process to two different blades, lets say homeUsers.blade.php and admin.blade.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logic is here:** The best way is to create two tables one `users` and another `roles`, and put `role_id` in users table as foreign key.Then create a relation that a role `belongsTo` a user.

However in your case if you have two views and you want to show one for admin and other for other users follow the below method.

Create two views which you want to use in your case 1) admin 2) homeUsers

```
@if(Auth::user()->isAdmin == 1)
  @include('admin') //admin.blade.php
@else
 @include('homeUsers') //homeUsers.blade.php
```

Comment: This seems the best option for me. I've tried solution which @Daniel proposed, but it is not working in my case. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but for now I will use your solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention for others who maybe have the same issue. It should be `@include('admin')` instead of `@include('admin.blade.php')`. (without extensions)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of Laravel you're using, but this seems like it should be in your Middleware.

Check out `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` in Middleware. Then, you could do the following.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->role == 'Admin')
        {
            return redirect('/admin');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/home')
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```